# loop simultaneously in excel vba?

Tags: vba, excel

I need help. I want to know if one can loop simultaneously ? As in put a condition like

```
For i = 1 to 3 and for j = 1 to 2
```

If not is there another way?

Comment: Will keep that in mind. But with a nested loop the value of the variable won't change simultaneously right? Because the for condition which is nested will keep running until it is complete.

Comment: in that case use `Do..While` loop and change `i` and `j` manually

Comment: The response by @simoco is the answer

Comment: by **simultaneously** you mean something like this `for (int i = 0, j = 1; j < 3; j++, i++)`? Are you sure you're not looking for a nested loop instead? What do you mean actually cause I can't understand what would you need the `For i = 1 to 3 and for j = 1 to 2` logic for?? That logic is not very logical anyway so can you elaborate or provide a SSCCE??

Comment: Tell us more about what you are trying to do. You may not need a parallel loop, but could get by with a nested loop. But we need more information to help more.

Comment: Basically I wanted that when i changes, j changes simultaneously.I just wanted to know if such parallelism is possible? Though I worked my way by expressing i in terms of j, so eliminating the requirement of parallel work

Answer (score -1):

VBA does not support parallelism. Depending on a task, values can be collected from multiple loops or nested loops may be used.